# IsChecked property in Firemonkey TListbox not returning correct result?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I am trying to use both IsChecked and IsSelected in conjunction with the FMX TListbox control and both are returning incorrect results (always True regardless of the user's selection).  Is this a known bug and is there a workaround?

My test code is pretty simple:

---

```
var
    i: integer;
    lb: TListboxitem;

for i:=0 to lbxPartners.items.Count-1 do
begin

  lb :=tlistboxitem(lbxPartners.Items[i]);
  if lb=nil then continue;

  if lb.IsChecked then
     memo1.Lines.Add('item '+inttostr(i) +' checked')
  else
     memo1.Lines.Add('item '+inttostr(i)+' unchecked');
end;
```

Comment: It should be lbxPartners.ListItems[i].

Comment: Mike, thanks for this - it works now, though I found that if I want to get the text of the item I still have to go to the .items stringlist; listitems[n].text throws an error.  Oh well, at least I now have it working!

Comment: I've written up a full answer for you. ListItems[n].Text works fine for me. What error do you get? Do you have a code sample?

Answer (score 4):

TListBox.Items is a list of strings, and is chiefly there so you can use the control in the same way as the VCL TListBox.

TListBox.ListItems is a list of TListBoxItems which are the child controls which are displayed by the TListBox.

To access the IsChecked property:

```
ListBox1.ListItems[n].IsChecked := True;
```

You can access the text with either:

```
ListBox1.Items[n] := 'Hello';
ListBox1.ListItems[n].Text := 'World';
```

Your full code would be (Note no need for a cast):

```
var i: integer; lb: TListboxitem;

for i:=0 to lbxPartners.items.Count-1 do begin
  lb := lbxPartners.ListItems[i];
  if lb=nil then continue;

  if lb.IsChecked then
     memo1.Lines.Add('item '+inttostr(i) +' checked')
  else
     memo1.Lines.Add('item '+inttostr(i)+' unchecked');
end;
```

Comment: Shouldn't ListBox1.Items[n].IsChecked := True; be ListBox1.ListItems[n].IsChecked := True; ?

Comment: yes,  only listitems[i].ischecked  works for me  (Delphi 10.4)